# How to reformat a string of words with commas/ampersands in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write some PHP code that will separate words when the are two with "&" and a comma when they are three and the last two with "&"

Something like this

$string = "stack over flow";
Print on screen like this "stack, over & flow";
Hope you noticed the comma and the ampersand.

Then when they are two words

$string = "stack overflow";
print like this echo "stack & overflow";

Here is my code I have been trying, but I am not getting it right:

```
    $string = '1,2';

$list = explode(',',$string);
foreach($list as $row) {
    if($list = 2) {
        echo '<a href="">'.$row.'</a> &';
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have your array of strings, you could get the last element with `array_pop`, then use `implode` to join the main array with commas, and then add the last one with an ampersand.

Comment: Careful with `$list = 2` - that is an assignment not a comparison.

Comment: (A belatedly approved edit here overwrote mine, so I have rolled the change back).

Answer (score 2):

This should take into account the possibilities of one or more words.  If there is more than one word, just remove the last word (using `array_pop()`) and `implode()` with `,`  the remaining words.

If there is only 1 word, the result is the same as the original string...

```
$string = "stack over"; 
$list = explode(" ", $string);
if ( count($list) > 1 ) {
    $last = array_pop($list);
    $result =  implode(", ", $list) . " & {$last}";
}
else    {
    $result = $string;
}
```

To add anchor tags to each word...

```
$list = explode(" ", $string);
$aTag = '<a href="#">';
if ( count($list) > 1 ) {
    $last = array_pop($list);
    $result =  $aTag.
        implode("</a>, {$aTag}", $list) . "</a> & {$aTag}{$last}</a>";
}
else    {
    $result = $aTag.$string."</a>";
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: the above code is just show a white page .$string = "stack over"; 
$list = explode(" ", $string);
if ( count($list) > 1 ) {
    $last = array_pop($list);
    $result =  implode(", ", $list) . " & {$last}";
}
else    {
    $result = $string;
}

Comment: thanks Nigel Ren... it real worked, thanks once once

Comment: but Nigel Ren , can you add <a href tag to each of the string expect the comma and & character, because am getting but the string and the character to be a link when i add htm a hef to $result

Comment: Can you show the full output you want, it will help.

Comment: something like this when is more than 1<a href="#">stack</a>, <a href ="#">over</a> & <a href="">flow</a>, and when is one <a href="#">stack</a>

Comment: I've corrected the problem, you can replace the `'` with `"`.

Comment: Nigel Ren please am not getting the words in the link tag... i mean like <a herf="stack">Stack</a>, <a href="over">over</a> & <a href="flow">Flow</a> rather am getting the last word for each of them

Comment: I thought you asked for `<a href="#">` as the link.

Comment: yes i did... check the link tag... it has the word as there url, am calling it up fom database whereby each tag has its own specify tag name, But the code gets code use the last word for all link for each tag. i mean $string = "stack over flow";

Answer (score 0):

thanks Nigel Ren.. you code was really helpfully
but their a correction i made.Here

```
    $string = "stack over flow";
$list = explode(" ", $string);
$aTag = '<a href="#">';
if ( count($list) > 1 ) {
    $last = array_pop($list);
    $result =  $aTag.
        implode('</a>, '.$aTag.'', $list) . "</a> & {$aTag}{$last}</a>";
}
else    {
    $result = $aTag.$string."</a>";
}
echo $result;
```

thanks